# How to find the remainder of $\binom{2013}{101}$ when it is divided by 101

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

I start first from the definition of 
$$\binom{n}r=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} $$
then I used the Wilson's theorem  for p is prime 
$$(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod p$$
now how we can continue??

Comment: Use `\binom{n}{r}` to get the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}r$, and `x \equiv y \pmod{p}` to get $x\equiv y\pmod p$ with better spacing.

Answer (score 6):

We have that $2013=19\cdot 101+94$, hence by [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem)

$$\binom{2013}{101}\equiv \binom{19}{1}\cdot\binom{94}{0}\equiv\color{red}{19}\pmod{101}.$$

Answer (score 5):

It is better if you use this formula instead:
$$\binom{2013}{101}=\frac{2013\cdot2012\cdot\ldots 1913}{101!}$$

The denominator is obviously a multiple of $101$, but not of $101^2$. Since $101^2>2013$, the same can be said about the numerator.

Simplify the factor $101$ from both, and you get $100!$ below. Above is a bit more complicated.

The only multiple of $101$ is $1919$, which is $19\cdot 101$. The remaining numbers form a *[complete residue system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteResidueSystem.html)* modulo $101$, so their product is congruent to $100!$, which cancels with the denominator.

Thus, the answer is $19$.